# Как наложить контент и ссылку на слайдер?

Tags: html, wordpress, вёрстка, css

Как наложить контент и ссылку на слайдер? Как на этом [сайте](http://renessans-center.ua/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В примере так

```
.hero-carousel article img { 
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    }
    .hero-carousel article .contents { 
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 24px;
    left: 40%;
    padding: 0%;
    top: 100px;
    width: 45%;
    }
    .hero-carousel article .contents { 
    list-style: none outside none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    }
    .hero-carousel article .contents h2 { 
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #666666;
    }
```

Comment: @soledar10 А можно ли как-то автоматизировать? Последние 4 добавленные записи выводились на слайдере (в слайдере 4 картинки)...